# How to mirror your android phone to android tablet?

Tags: screen-mirroring

My android phone has got a feature called screen mirroring. But on my tablet it's called smart view. When I turn it ON on both the devices, for some reason they're not able to detect each other. Phone is from Sony and tablet from Samsung. Though both are android devices but still use different terminologies. Any ideas of how I could get them work together?

[image: picture of phone & tablet]

Answer (score 1):

There is an app on the Google Play Store that does exactly what your looking for.

[AirMirror: Remote support & Remote control devices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airmirror&referrer=utm_source%3Dwww_index)

> Remote Control AirMirror fulfills the goal to control one Android
> phone with another phone.
> *This feature needs AirDroid installed on the other end, and log in with the same email account.
>
> You can apply AirMirror with the following features:
>
> Remote Control Directly control another phone/tablet, do whatever you
> like, no matter where this device is.
> *If the controlled device is not rooted, it is required to process Non-Root setting through AirDroid PC beforehand.
>
> Remote Camera Access another phone's view from either front camera or
> rear camera. You can put this phone as a family security camera,
> guarding your family's safety.
>
> Screen Mirroring Check your device's screen anytime in real-time.
>
> *If you want to control Android devices through PC, you can use AirDroid PC client.
>
> Remote Support You can easily assist your friend or family to solve
> mobile device issues through Remote Support.
> *This function needs AirDroid Remote Support installed on the other end.
>
> Overview:
>
> Quick Connection by 9-digit Connection Code No account is required,
> your friend or family can connect to you simply by their 9-digit
> Connection Code.
>
> Screen Sharing Send the screen sharing request with one tap, and you
> can see the device screen in real-time.
>
> Voice Call AirMirror provides clear voice communication, you can
> simply call and talk, saving time for texting.
>
> Tutorial Gesture Swipe or tap on the shared screen, the Tutorial
> Gesture will show on your friend or familyˇs device. Follow to easily
> solve the problem.
>
> Voice Message and Text If you are under a surrounding not suitable for
> making a call, you can still communicate through sending texts,
> pictures and voice messages.
>
> AirMirror facilitates your life. If there is any problem during your
> experience in AirMirror, feel free to give us feedback anytime. Thank
> you very much for your support of AirMirror!

Comment: I was hoping for a default App that is already installed. For example, I successfully shared my phone to my TV by using the default apps. Both were from Sony. Something, without asking for email, or any other personal information?